# reading from a table with very large data

Tags: mysql, sql

assume there is a table which has 3 **integer** data type columns in it and there are **2 billion** records stored in this table.
**combination of 3 columns are PK.**

Can MySQL handle a table like this for fast reading and writing.
reading and writing speed won't slow down?

MySQL version: 5.6 or later.
Server : 2GB Ram

Comment: Facebook uses mysql :)

Comment: facebook is using cassandra - non-SQL

Comment: frozen smile : http://www.mysql.com/customers/view/?id=757

Comment: well, I think facebook's servers are very powerfull, I'm going to read from this table on a simple server which has 2GB Ram.

Comment: ah in that case u should be bothering about your ram and server not mysql.

Comment: Define fast and slow - what kind of performance numbers are you looking for? Can you put one million records in the table and benchmark your application to get an estimate?